# EC2: Unable to rvm install ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/) and am stuck at trying to install ruby using rvm (scroll down to see the command in the link)

I have searched online for a variety of solutions but nothing seems to work. How can I resolve the issues below?

> rvm install ruby
>
> Searching for binary rubies, this might take some
>   time.
>
> Found remote file
>   https://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2
>   Checking requirements for ubuntu.
>
> Installing requirements for ubuntu.
>   mkdir: cannot create directory
>   ‘/usr/local/rvm/log/1463248047_ruby-2.3.0’: Permission denied
>
> tee:
>   /usr/local/rvm/log/1463248047_ruby-2.3.0/update_system.log: No such
>   file or directory
>
> Updating system......... Error running
>   'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.3.0',
>
> showing last 15 lines
>   of /usr/local/rvm/log/1463248047_ruby-2.3.0/update_system.log
>
> tail:
>   cannot open
>   ‘/usr/local/rvm/log/1463248047_ruby-2.3.0/update_system.log’ for
>   reading: No such file or directory Requirements installation failed
>   with status: 1.

Notes for debugging:

1) The previous steps to install rvm have been taken already. Mainly:

```
su - deploy
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

2) I tried running `sudo rvm install ruby`, but got the following error

> sudo: rvm: command not found

Comment: Have you download and install rvm package already ?

Comment: Try running with sudo

Comment: yes have downloaded and installed the package, as per the tutorial in the link.

Comment: when i try running with sudo - i get this sudo: rvm: command not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change permissions to rvm directory by this command:

```
sudo chmod -R a+xwr /usr/local/rvm
```

Comment: This worked. Not sure why someone voted your answer down, i've voted it up, it shld have positive points. thanks lots.

Comment: @RPV I was the downvoter. Yes, it works, but it creates a serious security problem. It's the equivalent of `chmod 777`, which is never the correct answer.

Comment: got it, is there a better solution? (thanks for explaining)

Comment: Better solution is installing rvm in your home directory `~/.rvm`